# Python break script but keep console open

Tags: python

Here is the basic code:

```
if pwd1 == pwd2:
    print ("correct password")
    break
```

How do I make it so that if pwd1 and pwd2 are equal the console window will stay open with the correct password message but the script execution will stop.

All of the above is in loop and if not stopped the user will be asked to reinput pwd2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    # ...
    if pwd1 == pwd2:
       break
else: # not found
    sys.exit("not found")

print("Found correct password:", pwd1)
input("Press Enter to exit") # keep console open
```